# How many mm of rain should fall into a greenhouse in order to store $160m^{3}$. The area is $6400m^{2}$

Tags: geometry, area

> How many mm of rain should fall into a  greenhouse in order to store
>   $160\text{m}^3$? The area is $6400\text{m}^2$.

In this case a "mm of rain" means that for 1Lt that is spilled over a surface of $1m^{2}$ the height is 1mm.

In this case I don´t know how to relate the $160m^{3}$ with this logic.

Comment: $\frac{\text{Volume}}{\text{Area}}=\frac{160}{6400}=25 \text{mm}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk : I suspect, based on the way the question is phrased, that converting  meters to millimeters may have been the principal difficulty, so that your comment fails to address that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
6400 \text{ m}^2 \times {\Large\text{?}} = 160 \text{ m}^3
$$
Dividing you get
$$
\frac{160 \text{ m}^3} {6400\text{ m}^2} = 0.025 \text{ m} = {\Large\text{?}} \text{ mm}
$$
Perhaps converting m to mm is where your difficulty lies. There will be $1000$ times as many mm as m. To multiply by $1000,$ move the decimal point three places to the right.

(Note that $\dfrac{\text{m}^3}{\text{m}^2} = \text{m}$.)

Answer (score 2):

$$
V = A\cdot h
$$
You have the height $h$ in millimeter = $(1/1000)$ meter, so
$$
160 \text{m}^3 = 6400 \text{m}^2 \cdot \left( h \cdot \frac{1 \text{m}}{1000 \text{mm}} \right)
$$
Now solve for $h$.

Comment: Thank you as well. Now I understand.